# Why unable to find limit for sequence $\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Need help in getting limit of sequence. This question is taken from section 3.2.1 of Chapter 3 of the CRM series book by MAA: Exploratory Examples for Real Analysis, By Joanne E. Snow, Kirk E. Weller.

I request to vet attempt; as well as help to find the solution.

It is not solvable as L'Hopital's rule applies for $\frac 0 0 $ or $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$ cases alone, & the form is $\frac 1{\infty}$.

> Q.3. Identify limit of Seq. 3 using calculus.
>   $$\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

Let, $f(n) = (\frac n{n+1})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, need find $f'(n)\approx\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta n}=
\lim_{\Delta n \to0 } (\frac{f(n+\Delta n)-f(n)}{(n+\Delta n)-n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$= \lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{f(n+h)-f(n)}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {n+h}{n+h+1}-\frac n{n+1}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {(n+h)(n+1) -(n)(n+h+1)}{(n+h+1)(n+1)}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {(n^2+n+nh+h) -(n^2+nh+n)}{(n^2+n+nh+h+n+1)}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {h}{(n^2+(n+1)h+2n+1)}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$
$=(\frac {1}{n^2+2n+1})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

---

*Edit :*

<del>I was actually concerned by formula-free aspect of analysis as compared to calculus, that meant to me to not use the Quotient rule of calculus.</del>

But, modifications are suggested by responses, by taking $\frac 1{1+\frac 1n}$, to get the desired limit of $1$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.
The desired result occurs by taking $\lim_{n\to \infty }(\frac 1{1+\frac 1n})= (\frac 1{1+\frac 10}) = 1$.

But, if take the limit by following my above approach, then still get the same result (as shown below).

Let, $f(n) = (\frac 1{1+\frac 1n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, need find $f'(n)\approx\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta n}=
\lim_{\Delta n \to0 } (\frac{f(n+\Delta n)-f(n)}{(n+\Delta n)-n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$= \lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{f(n+h)-f(n)}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac 1{1+\frac 1{n+h}}-\frac 1{1+\frac 1n}} {h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {n+h}{n+h+1} -\frac {n}{n+1}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {(n^2+n+nh+h) -(n^2+nh+n)}{(n^2+n+nh+h+n+1)}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

$=\lim_{h\to0 }(\frac{\frac {h}{(n^2+(n+1)h+2n+1)}}{h})_{n=1}^{\infty}$
$=(\frac {1}{n^2+2n+1})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

So, what is the flaw in my approach?

In my approach, the $\lim_{h\to0 }$ is relevant by taking infinitesimal differences in domain. So, should the $\lim_{h\to0 }$ part be ignored? If so, on what basis?

Comment: Isn't it of the form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$?  So use Lhôpital's.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Please elaborate as don't see $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, L'Hôpital's applies whenever we have a limit of the form $\dfrac 00$ or $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$.

$\dfrac n{n+1}$ is one of the latter type, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n+1=\infty$.

Now I'll leave the application of the theorem to you.

Comment: Yes, can find by taking derivative of both numerator and denominator to get $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1}$. Also, I am erroneous in post as finding derivative rather than limit. Must be very confused.

Comment: That's ok.  You are right.  Also, it is easy without L'Hôpital's.  Just factor out $n$, and note $\dfrac 1n\to0$ as $n\to\infty $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$\frac{n}{n+1}$$ as $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: so, all the part concerning $n+h$ for $\lim_{h\to0 }$ is not needed, but why? I was under the impression that (at least in real analysis, as the book is for that) this is the approach stated to be formula-free. Even one book on real analysis brags about the formula-free nature of real analysis as compared to calculus, in its preface.

Comment: It is reduced to a converged sequence, since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$

Comment: Why not write $n/(n+1) = 1 - 1/(n+1)$ to skip a step? Just a limit of a sum and not a limit of a reciprocal and a sum.

Comment: But the reduction should not have become a necessity. I.e., if the problem is solvable by reduction, then it should be otherwise too. Or, is it that I am wrong?

Comment: Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 2):

For large enough $n$, the behaviour of $n$ and $n+1$ are the same. In other words in the limiting sense they are equal. So the limit is $1$.