# Show that the $n$-th Fibonacci number is given by $\frac{\cosh na}{\cosh a}$ or $\frac{\sinh na}{\cosh a}$, where $\sinh a=1/2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

This question is taken from book: Advanced Calculus: An Introduction to Classical Analysis, by Louis Brand. The book is concerned with introductory real analysis.

I request to help find the solution.

> Show that the general term of Fibonacci sequence $1,1,2,3,5,\cdots$, is given by :
> $f_n = \frac{\cosh\, n\alpha}{\cosh\, \alpha}$ ($n$ odd), 
> $f_n = \frac{\sinh\, n\alpha}{\cosh\, \alpha}$ ($n$ even),
> where $\sinh \alpha= \frac 12$, and that $\lim \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} = e^\alpha.$

As given [here](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/11-3/hoggatt1.pdf):
The hyperbolic functions $\sinh$, $\cosh $ are given by:
$$\sinh\,z = \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}, \cosh\,z = \frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{2}$$
where $\,z= x+iy\,\,$ is a complex variable.
These functions satisfy the identities:
$$\cosh^2\,z-\sinh^2\,z = 1,\,\, \cosh\,iy = \cosh\,y,\,\, \sinh\,iy = i\,\sinh\,y$$

If $\sinh\,z = \frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2} = \frac 12$, then $\cosh^2\,z-\sinh^2\,z = 1\,\,$ gives $\cosh^2\,z=\frac 54$

This yields nothing, so consider opposite approach of taking help by another means of generating Fibonacci sequence terms.

Say, the polynomial $f(x) = x+1$ yields terms for successive values for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ as $2,3,\dots$.

So, took help from paper [here](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/8-4/bicknell.pdf) that concerns with fibonacci polynomials, with text portion from page 1 copied below:

> The Fibonacci polynomials $\{F_n (x)\}$ are defined by
>
> (1.1) $F_1(x) = 1, F_2(x) = x$, and $F_{n+1}(x) = xF_n(x) + F_{n-1}x$.
>
> Notice that, when $x = 1, F_n(1) = F_n$ , the $n$ Fibonacci number. It is easy
> to verify that the relation 
> (1.2) $F_{-n}(x) = (-1)^{n+1} F_n(x)$
> extends the definition of Fibonacci polynomials to all integral subscripts.

But, this also doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try a proof by induction?

Comment: @MartinR Never thought that way.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a general formula for the Fibonacci numbers given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/how-to-prove-that-the-binet-formula-gives-the-terms-of-the-fibonacci-sequence.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I do not see a connect to this post. Anyway, the selected solution is above my current level. Only the one at last (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2706929/424260) is comprehensible. I request a simpler approach that can easily connect to the post.

Comment: @MartinR Request elaboration as am confused that for given $\sinh \alpha= \frac 12$, how to apply induction. Better post an answer.

Comment: Properly, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f_{n+1}/f_n)=e^{\alpha}\not=e{\alpha}$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks. But, an answer towards finding the limit would be too much helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint for induction. By the addition formula for $\cosh$ (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Sums_of_arguments)),
$$\cosh((n+1)\alpha)=\cosh(n\alpha)\cosh(\alpha)+\sinh(n\alpha)\sinh(\alpha)$$
and 
$$\cosh((n-1)\alpha)=\cosh(n\alpha)\cosh(\alpha)-\sinh(n\alpha)\sinh(\alpha).$$
Hence 
$$\cosh((n+1)\alpha)-\cosh((n-1)\alpha)=2\sinh(n\alpha)\sinh(\alpha)$$
and, after dividing by $\cos(\alpha)$, if $n$ is even we get
$$f_{n+1}-f_{n-1}=2f_{n}\sinh(\alpha)=f_n\implies f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}.$$
In a similar way, by using the addition formula for $\sinh$, we verify that the same recurrence holds when $n$ is odd.

As regards the limit you may use the unified formula
$$f_n=\frac{e^{n\alpha} - (-1)^ne^{-n\alpha}}{e^{\alpha}+e^{-\alpha}}$$
Since $\alpha>0$, it follows that, as $n\to \infty$,
$$\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}=\frac{e^{(n+1)\alpha} - (-1)^{n+1}e^{-(n+1)\alpha}}{e^{n\alpha} - (-1)^ne^{-n\alpha}}\to e^{\alpha}.$$

P.S. Note that $e^{\alpha}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\varphi$ is the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) and therefore the above unified formula can be written as
$$f_n=\frac{\varphi^n-(-1)^n\varphi^{-n}}{\varphi+\varphi^{-1}}=\frac{\varphi^n-(-\varphi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
which is the usual [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Very much thanks. Hope that the answer will cover the limit part too.

Comment: @jiten See my edit.